# Connecting to MySQL with Ecto in Docker

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, elixir, ecto

I am in the process of Dockerizing my project, and the following is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  server:
    image: server
    environment:
      DB_HOST: 0.0.0.0
      DB_DATABASE: dev
      DB_PORT: 3306
      DB_USER: dev
      DB_PASSWORD: dev
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_started
  database:
    image: mysql:latest
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: dev
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: dev
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dev
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  mysql_data:
```

and the `Dockerfile` for `server`:

```
FROM elixir:latest

EXPOSE 4000

RUN mkdir /server
COPY . /server
WORKDIR /server

RUN mix local.rebar --force
RUN mix local.hex --force
RUN mix deps.get

RUN mix do compile

CMD [ "sh", "/server/entry.sh" ]
```

where `entry.sh` is:

```bash
# Exit on failure
set -e

mix ecto.create
mix ecto.migrate
mix run priv/repo/seeds.exs

exec mix phx.server
```

When I run this using `docker compose up`, I get an error that Phoenix can't connect to the MySQL database. I have tried using hosts `0.0.0.0` and `localhost`, however both don't work.

This is the corresponding section of my `config/dev.exs`:

```
config :app, App.Repo
  username: System.get_env("DB_USER"),
  password: System.get_env("DB_PASSWORD"),
  hostname: System.get_env("DB_HOST"),
  database: System.get_env("DB_DATABASE"),
  port: 3306,
  stacktrace: true,
  pool_size: 10
```

The following is the exact error message I get:

```
server-1    | 11:23:07.417 [error] GenServer #PID<0.272.0> terminating
server-1    | ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) (0.0.0.0:3306) connection refused - :econnrefused
server-1    |     (db_connection 2.4.3) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:100: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
server-1    |     (connection 1.1.0) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
server-1    |     (stdlib 4.2) proc_lib.erl:240: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
server-1    | Last message: nil
server-1    | State: MyXQL.Connection
server-1    |
server-1    | 11:23:07.430 [error] GenServer #PID<0.278.0> terminating
server-1    | ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) (0.0.0.0:3306) connection refused - :econnrefused
server-1    |     (db_connection 2.4.3) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:100: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
server-1    |     (connection 1.1.0) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
server-1    |     (stdlib 4.2) proc_lib.erl:240: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
server-1    | Last message: nil
server-1    | State: MyXQL.Connection
server-1    | ** (Mix) The database for App.Repo couldn't be created: %RuntimeError{message: "killed"}
server-1 exited with code 1
```

Comment: You need to use the Compose service name `database` as the MySQL host name.  `127.0.0.1` is the current (Elixir) container, and `0.0.0.0` means a vague "everywhere" (interpreted the same as `127.0.0.1` for outbound connections).

Comment: @DavidMaze I just tried changing it to `database` and got the same error - I can confirm it changed as the error line became `server-1    | ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) (database:3306) connection refused - :econnrefused` - I also tried changing the MySQL environment 'MYSQL_HOST' to `database` as well, to no avail

Comment: Is the Elixir application starting before the database is fully initialized?  Do you see MySQL startup messages after the `server-1 exited ...` line in the `docker-compose up` output?

Comment: @DavidMaze That was a thought I had too - I do see MySQL startup messages following it, however from what I can tell, the line `restart: on-failure` in `docker-compose.yml` keeps the server restarting when it exits (which it does), and even after the MySQL startup messages have all finished, I still get the same error over and over ^^